# magento 2 custom collection pager with dynamic url

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I use backend option to set an url for my page, now i want to add pager to that page:

```
$pager = $this->getLayout()
    ->createBlock(
        'Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager',
        'module.custom.pager'
    )->setAvailableLimit(array(2=>2))
    ->setShowPerPage(true)
    ->setCollection(
        $this->getCustomCollection()
);
$this->setChild('pager', $pager);
```

this code adds pager but it shows module URL(specified in route.xml) URL if we use pager and not the specified one.

```
public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
{
    $path = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
    $array = explode('/', $path);
    if(strpos($path, $this->getFrontendUrl()) !== false) {
        $request->setModuleName('modulename')
            ->setControllerName('index')
            ->setActionName('index');
        if(isset($array[1])){
            $request->setParam('param', $array[1]);
        }
   } else {
       return false;
   }
   return $this->actionFactory->create(
       'Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward',
       ['request' => $request]
   );
}
/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getFrontendUrl(){
    return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('section/group/customurl', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
}
```

one option which I'm aware of is to use URL rewrites, is there any other way?

Comment: please explain briefly

Comment: I have url which we set in backend for module, pager uses url specified in routes.xml.
need that pager would use url from backend and not from routes.xml

Comment: added my code to repository: https://github.com/Naberdz/producttags

you can see the problem when you visit tag page and try to use pager.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my problem by creating custom pager and adjusted getPagerUrl function to match needed result

controller _prepareLayout function to initialize pager:

```
$pager = $this->getLayout()
    ->createBlock(
       'Wemessage\ProductTags\Block\CustomPager',
       'wemessage.tags.pager'
    )->setAvailableLimit(array(2=>2))
    ->setShowPerPage(true)
    ->setCollection(
        $this->getTaggedCollection()
    );
$this->setChild('pager', $pager);
$this->getTaggedCollection()->load();
```

custom pager :

```
class CustomPager extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $_scopeConfig;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context  $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Wemessage\ProductTags\Model\TagsFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFrontendSlug(){
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('producttags/options/tagslug', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve page URL by defined parameters
     *
     * @param array $params
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPagerUrl($params = [])
    {
        $urlParams = [];
        $urlParams['_current'] = true;
        $urlParams['_escape'] = true;
        $urlParams['_use_rewrite'] = true;
        $urlParams['_fragment'] = $this->getFragment();
        $urlParams['_query'] = $params;
        return str_replace('producttag/index/index', $this->getFrontendSlug(), $this->getUrl($this->getPath(), $urlParams)); //producttag defined in routes.xml
    }
}
```